# If I turn off my Find My iPhone will it send a notification to the account holder?

Tags: ios, icloud, notifications, find-my-iphone

If I turn off Find My iPhone on my iPhone 5 does it send any notification to the email address attached to the apple id or send a notification of any kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, disabling Find My iPhone on a device with an active Find My iPhone activation state will send an email to the email on file for the Apple ID that the iCloud account is tied to.

[image: Find My iPhone disabled email]